# Customtkinter Textbox default height problem

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, customtkinter

The problem is related to the height of the TextBox. From what I see there is a default value but here is the big problem: I don't know and can't find on Tom's documentation how to adjust the box to fit the text. I want to make an app that will display a green box if the operation has finished succesfully and red if the operation failed. It does that, but I can't fit the text.
The TextBox goes way beyond the text without actually taking it in consideration.

```
import customtkinter as ctk


class MainBox(ctk.CTk):
    def __init__(self):
        # Main windows specifications
        super().__init__()
        self.button_click = None
        self.title(' Utility Box')
        self.geometry('850x430')
        self.resizable(False, False)
        self.configure(bg='#222629')
        self.iconbitmap(r'D:\2xProjects\Python\UtilityBox\resources\appicon.ico')
        self.toplevel_window = None
        self.numberentries = 0

        self.log_frame = ctk.CTkScrollableFrame(master=self, width=580, height=360, corner_radius=20, border_width=1, border_color='#474B4F')
        self.log_frame.grid(row=0, column=2, padx=15, pady=(13, 0))

    def update_log(self, log_message: str, specific_operation_color: str) -> None:
        log_text = ctk.CTkTextbox(self.log_frame, width=560, fg_color=specific_operation_color, font=('Helvetica', 12, 'bold'))
        log_text.grid(row=self.numberentries, column=0, pady=(0, 10), sticky='w')

        log_text.insert(ctk.END, log_message)
        self.numberentries += 1


if __name__ == '__main__':
    mainbox = MainBox()
    mainbox.mainloop()
```

```
class SearchWindow(ctk.CTkToplevel):
    def __init__(self, mainbox):
        super().__init__()
        self.title(' Search details')
        self.geometry('252x365')
        self.resizable(False, False)
        self.configure(bg='#222629')
        self.iconbitmap(r'D:\2xProjects\Python\UtilityBox\resources\Search.ico')
        self.operation_unique_identifier = 'Search'
```

Here are some images with the problem:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/QfBXh.jpg
https://i.stack.imgur.com/dBvuW.jpg

I don't know if I can solve this using a build in solution or it might require for me the calculate the height depending of the number of lines that I have in the text, but I can't really figure it out...

I attached Mainbox class which is the main window of the app where I have the log (the lines with green and red from the images)

Thank you

Small problem: I also noticed that the search window will not have the icon updated. I added it also if you can figure out the problem.
The path is good, it worked on tkinter (this app used to be tkinter and now I try to convert it to a customtkinter)

Comment: Please try to make a smaller [mcve]. There seems to be a whole lot of code that is unrelated to making a text widget fit its contents.

Comment: No, not really. If you're trying to fit a text widget to its contents, we don't need much more than the text widget, the contents, and enough extra code to make it run and illustrate what you've tried.

Comment: @BryanOakley I deleted the code that was not important from the both classes and now I described the things a little bit better. It's ok now?

Comment: In my opinion its still far too long. The code that does the search is irrelevant, you can just hard-code some messages to illustrate the problem. The window icon, title, and resizable attributes seem to be irrelevant. Create a single window, add a single button that adds a random log message, and show us the code where you're trying to control the size of the text. That's really all we need.

Comment: @BryanOakley I eliminated everything that is extra. Now it's just the MainBox and the frames that are related to the problem and only the function that actually matter. I'm sorry for the initial version but thank you for your patience. I try to learn to make a constructive post on this platform. I'm new, I had only 1 post before.

Comment: There's nothing in your code that calls `updateLog`. We have to be able to run your code to reproduce the error.

Comment: Why don't you just use a `CTkLabel` instead of `CTkTextbox`? For the icon issue of `CTkToplevel`, it is a design bug.  Workaround is to delay the update the icon by at least 200ms using `.after()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `count` method of a text widget to count the amount of pixels used by a block of text.

Unfortunately this method isn't exposed in the customtkinter widget. However, you can call it on the embedded text widget. This could break in future versions of customtkinter, since the only way to access it is via a private member of the class.

```
def update_log(self, log_message: str, specific_operation_color: str) -> None:
    ...
    log_text.insert(ctk.END, log_message)
    height = log_text._textbox.count("1.0", "end", "ypixels", "update")
    log_text.configure(height=height)
    ...
```